# reshape in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dimensions, reshape

If we come to the following line of code in `MATLAB`:

```
reshape(dataSet{i},1, 200*200);
```

- Here, `dataset{j}` seems to be an element in a **cell array**. Is that right? Since we are using `reshape`, can we say that that element is an `array`?
- When we use `reshape`, we define the dimensions (i.e; m,n). In the code above, is `m=1` and `n=200*200`? But, why wasn't `n` written as `400` for instance? Is there some reason for writing it in the syntax that we see?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean 200*200 = 40000 and not 400.

Answer (score 2):

`dataSet` is a cell array but you can't assume that `dataset{j}` is an array.  Reshape will work on strings and cell arrays as well:

```
reshape({1,2,3,4},2,2)

ans =

    [1]    [3]
    [2]    [4]

>> reshape('abcd',2,2)

ans =

ac
bd
```

There's not an obvious reason to write 200*200 unless 200 is important to understanding what is being computed.

Comment: Presumably `dataset{j}` is a square array of whatever datatype. Equivalent flattening would be achieved by replacing `200*200` with `[]`. Maybe the writer wants to emphasise the dimensions for whatever reason as Molly suspects; or maybe they're unaware/indifferent to the `[]` functionality and can't be bothered to calculate & hard code the product.